# Dropdown not working in navbarpage using bootstrap for R Shiny App

Tags: r, twitter-bootstrap, shiny

Here is my UI code dealing with the navbar

```
# ui.R

shinyUI(

navbarPage(theme = "bootstrap.min.css", "My Application",
tabPanel("Engine"),
navbarMenu("Models", tabPanel("Model 1"),
tabPanel("Model 2")),
tabPanel("Summary Stats"),
```

The main tab items should be "Engine", "Models" and "Summary Stats".  The Models tab should drop down with 2 options, Model 1 and Model 1.

when I click on "Models" nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

```
    library(shiny)

shinyUI(

  navbarPage(theme = "bootstrap.css", "My Application",
             tabPanel("Engine"),
             navbarMenu("Models", tabPanel("Model 1"),
                        tabPanel("Model 2")),
             tabPanel("Summary Stats")
  )
)
```

Seems  to be working great for me